# How to toggle a SonoffS31 flashed with Tasmota via OpenHAB and MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, sonoff, openhab

I have a SonoffS31 flashed with Tasmota. I have set up a Raspberry Pi running OpenHAB and an MQTT broker. In the paper UI of openHAB, I have created a Thing that represents the switch.

I have set the MQTT state topic of the switch to: `stat/sonoffS31-1/POWER` and it correctly displays the switch's state when I manually change the switch.

I have set the MQTT command topic to: `cmnd/sonoffS31-1/Power`.

My problem is that this command only allows me to turn off the switch via the openHAB UI. If I attempt to turn on the switch (via the UI) it just returns to the off position.

What is the correct MQTT command topic to toggle the switch?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I was not specifying a payload for the command. Specifying a payload for the on and off commands fixed my problem.